# How to get user who visited website more than once within 60 day after first visit

Tags: sql

I tried to write the SQL code using a self-join but I can't figure out what's wrong:

```
SELECT a.user_id,
       a.visit_dt
FROM   dataset1 a 
JOIN   dataset1 b ON a.user_id = b.user_id
                  AND abs(datediff(day, a.visit_dt, b.visit_dt)) < 60;
```

The new dataset should only have a list of user_ids and their first visit_dt

Answer (score 0):

`JOIN` is like Russian Matryoshka dolls, you need to do A B B A (in contrast to A B A B).

Let's say your table is just `data_set` (and without the table posted it is on you to make sure you're joining the correct columns):

```
SELECT * 
FROM data_set AS d1 
INNER JOIN data_set AS d2 ON (d2.id = d1.id)
```

You also forgot to use the `WHERE` in your query. Just do a `SELECT *` to test your `INNER JOIN` *first* and then refine your `WHERE` clause. I don't know your table setup so this one I can't answer without you having posted the code.

```
WHERE abs(datediff(day, a.visit_dt, b.visit_dt)) < 60;
```

Also completely ignore people who say you need to prefix all your column names; e.g. use `id` instead of `user_id` though for your columns use at *least* two words. Search engines prefer dashes in URLs so use underscores as your universal deliminator for functional code outside of URLs. That will help once you've refined your coding policies by making sure your naming conventions eliminate find/replace collisions (look up Advanced Find and Replace). Make good use of alias (`AS`), e.g. `a1.id` and you'll have some solid SQL to work with. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use `lead()` and other window functions:

```
SELECT d.user_id, d.visit_dt
FROM (SELECT d.*,
             LEAD(d.visit_dt) OVER (PARTITION BY d.user_id ORDER BY d.visit_dt) as next_visit_dt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.user_id ORDER BY d.visit_dt) as seqnum
      FROM dataset1 d
     ) d
WHERE seqnum = 1 AND
      d.next_visit_dt < DATEADD(day, 60, d.visit_dt);
```

Alternatively, use `EXISTS`:

```
select d.user_id, min(d.visit_dt)
from dataset d
group by d.user_id
having exists (select 1
               from dataset d2
               where d2.user_id = d.user_id and
                     d2.visit_dt > min(d.visit_dt) and
                     d2.visit_dt < dateadd(day, 60, min(d.visit_dt)
              );
```